# how to build a function like "list? function"

Tags: list, racket

How to simulation "list? function" by define-struct.

I want to define struct to binary tree and check each mycons's right node is make-mycons or empty.

Only focus on check right node needed be mycons or empty.

(I already found list?'s sourece code from github but it beyond my ability.)

```
#lang racket
(define-struct mycons (left right) #:mutable #:transparent)

(define (mylist? l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) #t]
    [(mycons? l) ...]
    [... ]))

(define correct (make-mycons (make-mycons 1 empty) (make-mycons 1 empty)))
(define wrong (make-mycons 3 (make-mycons 2 4)))

;;; expect
(equal? (mylist? empty) #t)
(equal? (mylist? correct) #t)
(equal? (mylist? wrong) #f)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple version of `list?`:

```
(define (my-list? x)   
  (cond
    [(eq? x '()) #t]
    [(pair? x)   (my-list? (cdr x))]
    [else       #f])
```

The builtin `list?` is smarter though. When `cons` is called it checks whether the last argument is a list and if it is, flips a bit in the internal representation of the cons cell. This means that the builtin `list?` is O(1) rather than O(n) as the solution above.

Comment: I've wondered about racket immutable lists being O(1) for `list?` since I've seen this in my performance tests.

Comment: I try (pair? (cons 3 4)) -> #t but i expect #f because the right node is empty or cons.

Comment: It's a pair, but not a list. A pair is the first pair of a list, only if its second element is a list.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But if we just use something like (cons 1 empty)
don't use (cons 1 2)
than we build this list. It will looks like binary tree.

And every left node is number every right node is cons or empty.

(cons 1 (cons 2 empty))
it's not like (cons 1 (cons 2 3))

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding what you are asking, but `(cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) ` is a list, and `(cons 1 (cons 2 3)) ` is not.

Comment: @tjorchrt You don't need to worry about the `car` (`left`), only the `cdr` (`right)` and it needs to be whatever you use as the empty list for your type or a `mycons` whose `right` attribute is `my-list?` as well.